# Multivariate Time Series Prediction at each timestep, i.e. return_sequences = TRUE

Tags: r, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm

I'm using **lstms in tensorflow R**, following this tutorial: https://blogs.rstudio.com/ai/posts/2017-12-20-time-series-forecasting-with-recurrent-neural-networks/

In this blog, the author predicts the temperature based on 14 variables. Specifically, for each time series, he uses one target output - something like this:

`(xt-4, xt-3, xt-2, xt-1, xt) => yt+1`.

However, I want to use a target variable at **every step**, so that the model outputs a prediction after receiving each timestep. This facilitates learning in my opinion. So this would look like this:

`(xt-4, xt-3, xt-2, xt-1, xt) => (yt-3, yt-2, yt-1, yt, yt+1)`.

I modified the code from the bloq to match my needs.

So here is my working example:

```
library(tibble)
library(readr)
fname <- file.path("./master_jena_climate_2009_2016.csv")
data <- read_csv(fname)

data <- data.matrix(data[,-1])


data <- data.matrix(data[,-1])

train_data <- data[1:200000,]
mean <- apply(train_data, 2, mean)
std <- apply(train_data, 2, sd)
data <- scale(data, center = mean, scale = std)

generator <- function(data, lookback, delay, min_index, max_index,
                      shuffle = FALSE, batch_size = 128, step = 6) {
  if (is.null(max_index))
    max_index <- nrow(data) - delay - 1
  i <- min_index + lookback
  function() {
    if (shuffle) {
      rows <- sample(c((min_index+lookback):max_index), size = batch_size)
    } else {
      if (i + batch_size >= max_index)
        i <<- min_index + lookback
      rows <- c(i:min(i+batch_size-1, max_index))
      i <<- i + length(rows)
    }
    samples <- array(0, dim = c(length(rows),
                                lookback / step,
                                dim(data)[[-1]]))
    targets <- array(0, dim = c(length(rows), lookback / step))# changed line!
    for (j in 1:length(rows)) {
      indices <- seq(rows[[j]] - lookback, rows[[j]]-1,
                     length.out = dim(samples)[[2]])
      samples[j,,] <- data[indices,]
      
      targets[j,] <- data[indices + delay,2] # changed line!
    }
    list(samples, targets)
  }
}
lookback <- 12
step <- 6
delay <- 144
batch_size <- 5

train_gen <- generator(
  data,
  lookback = lookback,
  delay = delay,
  min_index = 1,
  max_index = 200000,
  shuffle = TRUE,
  step = step, 
  batch_size = batch_size
)

val_gen = generator(
  data,
  lookback = lookback,
  delay = delay,
  min_index = 200001,
  max_index = 300000,
  step = step,
  batch_size = batch_size
)

test_gen <- generator(
  data,
  lookback = lookback,
  delay = delay,
  min_index = 300001,
  max_index = NULL,
  step = step,
  batch_size = batch_size
)

# How many steps to draw from val_gen in order to see the entire validation set
val_steps <- (300000 - 200001 - lookback) / batch_size

# How many steps to draw from test_gen in order to see the entire test set
test_steps <- (nrow(data) - 300001 - lookback) / batch_size
```

So for dummy purpose, I set the number of lookbacks to two, that is we have two timesteps from each feature to predict the temperature. When looking at the target variable for one batch, it looks like this:

```
p <- train_gen()
[[2]]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  1.3287346  1.0034035
[2,] -1.4128573 -1.3902648
[3,] -0.6831217 -0.9045275
[4,] -0.1058850  0.1742612
[5,] -2.8429583 -2.8248844
```

That is, each **row** represents an training instance and instead of one target value we have now **two, one for each timesteps**. So know I build the like this:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_lstm(units = 32, input_shape = list(NULL, dim(data)[[-1]]),
             return_sequences = TRUE) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1)

model %>% compile(
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
  loss = "mae"
)
history <- model %>% fit_generator(
  train_gen,
  steps_per_epoch = 500,
  epochs = 20,
  validation_data = val_gen,
  validation_steps = val_steps
)
```

So with this setup, the model training throws no error and using the model to predict some test data also gives me two value per test instance.

```
test <- test_gen()
ret <- predict(model, test[[1]])
            [,1]        [,2]
[1,] -0.05036402 -0.13460255
[2,] -0.04270903 -0.09078678
[3,] -0.05308574 -0.09126315
[4,] -0.04326173 -0.06756309
[5,] -0.03173561 -0.06674483
```

However, when I set `return_sequences = FALSE`,
the training also **does not throw any error**. My expectation would be some error that the target variable must be 1d instead of 2d. So as no error occurs, this makes me wonder if the loss function correctly uses the prediction at each timestep and the corresponding target for training the model. **How does the model know which target value to choose when the lstm layer does only return 1 single value??**